# Cauchy-Riemann conditions, how to obtain them from arbitrary directions

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $z$, in a sense that 
$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta z} = \lim_{(\Delta x + i \Delta y) \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta u(x,y) + i\Delta v(x,y)}{\Delta x + i \Delta y} $$

exists independent of the direction in which $\Delta z $ approaches $0$, then I can derive the C-R conditions by using two particular paths, namely ones parallel to the axes. But surely it must be possible to obtain the same result in a more complicated way, namely by using two arbitrary paths (straight lines), where $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = m_1$ and $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = m_2$. But so far, doing this computation has led me nowhere.

Comment: +1. However, I suggest you give up. The problem is just that you are getting lost in computations, IMHO. Taking two arbitrary directions (but linearly independent, of course), you will end up with a system of PDE for the directional derivatives. After some amount of computations this will reduce to the CR system that you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should assume that $f$ is differentiable at $z$ in the real sense, that is, 
$$f(z+h)=f(z)+Ah+o(|h|),\quad h\to 0 \tag1$$
where $A$ is a real $2\times 2$ matrix and complex number $h$ is interpreted as a real vector. (Without the differentiability assumption, directional derivatives may exist but be completely unrelated to partial derivatives.)

Every linear map $h\mapsto Ah$ in two dimensions can be written in terms of complex coefficients as $h\mapsto \alpha h+\beta \bar h$.  Hence, getting the same limit of $\Delta f/\Delta z$ in two independent directions amounts to $(\alpha h+\beta \bar h)/h$ being the same for two linearly independent vectors $h$. The latter is possible only when $\beta=0$, because the numbers $\bar h/h=1/h^2$ are different for the two vectors. Since $\beta=0$, the limit is the same for *all* directions, and we have the conclusion.